# Why i am getting null value for getNetworkCountryIso() in xperia?

Tags: android, mobile-country-code

I am getting null value for getNetworkCountryIso() in xperia(android) without sim. but it is working fine in other devices like samsung and LG.

Comment: Are you sure you getting this value on samsung and LG without sim card? I mean, as far as I know, you will always get null without sim, or while using airplane mode.

Comment: I am able to get the getNetworkCountryIso() in samsung with the wifi and no sim.TelephonyManager manager= (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);String serial= manager.getNetworkCountryIso();
 telephony_id.setText(serial); In case of xperia without sim , with wifi the getNetworkCountryIso() is null

Comment: According to the [sourcecode](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java) `getNetworkCountryIso()` should return an empty string and not null as default